# Max width for table with auto layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table with multiple columns and this table should not exceed a certain width *y*.

The columns of this table are automatically sized by the table-layout: auto.

But sometimes the columns get too big (the text should not be wrapped, it should be clipped) and sum up to a width bigger than *y*.

In this case i want the 'biggest' columns to become smaller until the widths of the columns don't exceed *y* anymore.

This means that i do not want to shrink alls columns by some factor but rather make the bigger columns "as small as neccessary".

Is this possible through some simple JS or even CSS?

**Here an example:**

I have 3 columns and a max total width y of 1000px.
Here the sizes of the content of the columns:

1: 100px 2: 1100px 3: 1300px

This should result in a table with those widths:

1: 100px 2: 450px 3: 450px;

Here some code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>SomeText</td>
            <td>SomeOtherTextSomeOtherTextSomeOtherText</td>
            <td>SomeLongerTextSomeLongerTextSomeLongerTextSomeLongerTextSomeLongerText</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid red; 
    width: 500px;
}

table {
    table-layout: auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6zJR4/2/

In this example the table is bigger than the containing div.
What i would want is that the table respects the width of the containing div and the columns shrink. But not all columns should shrink with the same factor e.g. 30% smaller. But the bigger columns (maybe all columns would need to shrink in the end) shrink.

My approach:
I want to let the browser calculate the 'ideal' sizes of the columns and then adjust the sizes by hand (=JS) to match the maximum width of the containing div.

How i am going to calculate the width of the different columns is not yet clear to me, i opened a mathoverflow question for that:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702067/how-to-find-a-set-of-ascending-natural-numbers-which-when-added-to-another-set-o

i hope there is a simpler solution.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Usually tables cells will shrink/wrap the text or whatever so it fits. In your case, I suspect there are long words or images in the column that's causing the issue. Can you post some code please

Comment: I added an example, i hope that clears what i want to archive.

Comment: Are the content of the cells all text or some images? if you can put this in a simple fiddle to demonstrate the issue, it would help

Comment: The columns contain text that should not be wrapped. In my example i used long single words to express that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented my own solution:

Here is the code showed in an example:

JS:

```
function findOptimalDistribution(Z, z) {
    // Make a working copy
    var Y = Z.slice(0);

    // Add dummy element so the 'lowest' value is 1, increment z accordingly
    Y.unshift(1);
    z++;

    // calculate sum of Y
    var R = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < Y.length; i++) {
        R += Y[i];
    }

    // R contains the remaining 'overlap' over z
    R -= z;

    // R <= 0 means the condition is already fullfiled
    if (R <= 0) {
        return Y.slice(1);
    }

    for(var i = Y.length - 1, u = 1; i > 0; i--, u++) {
        var c = (Y[i] - Y[i - 1]);

        var b = (R <= c*u);
        if (b) {
            c = Math.floor(R / u);
        }

        for(var j = Y.length - 1; j >= i; j--) {
            Y[j] -= c;
        }
        R -= c * u;

        // Subtract the remainder of R, that got 'lost' due to rounding (Math.floor)
        if (b) {
            for (var j = i; j < i + R; j++) {
                Y[j]--;
            }

            R = 0;
        }

        if (R == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return Y.slice(1);
}

function findOptimalWidths(columns, max_width) {    
    columns.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.width - b.width;
    });

    var X = columns.map(function(e) {           
        return e.width;
    });

    var optimal = findOptimalDistribution(X, max_width);

    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        columns[i].width = optimal[i];
    }

    return columns; 
}

function resizeColumns(){
    var columns = [];
    $('table tr:first-child td').each(function(i, e) {
        var $e = $(e);

        $e.css('max-width', 'auto');
        columns.push({elem: $e, width: $e.outerWidth()});
    });



    columns = findOptimalWidths(columns, $('div').innerWidth());

    for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        columns[i].elem.css('max-width', columns[i].width);
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeColumns();
});

resizeColumns();
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: violet;">
                Line
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: green;">
                LongerLineLongerLineLongerLine
            </td>
            <td style="background-color: yellow;">
               VeryLongLineVeryLongLineVeryLongLineVeryLongLineVeryLongLineVeryLongLineVeryLongLineVeryLongLine
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujQh7/2/

I believe this is a good and intuitiv behaviour of a table with columns that get truncated.

Answer (score 6):

Just use CSS to set TD (table data)

```
td {
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

Setting a max on table data will guarantee that no column exceeds that width (but may grow in height if overlap isnt specified)

If you want to have different max widths for differnt columns, make multiple classes:

```
 .col1 {
     max-width: 500px;
 }

 .col2 {
      max-width: 600px;
 }
```

etc. then just add a class to TD tag. If the table is dynamically created use JQuery to add the class:

```
 $( "td" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );
```

Comment: i not want the same max-width for all columns, since some could exceed  800 for your example.

Comment: Is this table created via jquery or javascript or is it HTML?

Comment: @NickRussler Using this code, the columns will be auto-sized to fit their contents **up to** 800px. They will not exceed it.

Comment: But when their content exceeds 800px they can't get bigger e.g. 900px.
If my total width is e.g. 1000px the first column only needs 100px but the seconds 1000px it should result in the first column having 100px and the second 900px.

Comment: @NickRussler Yes... isn't that what you're asking for? Why would you want the width to reach 900px if you don't want the width to exceed 800px?

Comment: @NickRussler So what you're asking for is not a max-width of 800px but a variable % width of the max container width?

Comment: Let's not waste time on this back and forth, get that fiddle up and I am sure the issue will solved promptly

Comment: @NickRussler I have updated my answer. Please review. Thumbs up if you like it :)

Comment: @Huangism The issue is not with what OP's code is doing, it's figuring out what OP wants the code to do. Posting a JSFiddle won't answer the question of "what do you want?", it simply answers the question of "what do you have?"

Comment: @MikeG010590 in my example i was talking about a total max size of 1000px so 900px + 100px = 1000px. I added an example to my question, i hopy that clears things up.

Comment: @TylerH it would be much easier to figure out what the issue is when we have some code.

Answer (score 1):

When the text is too long we can break them by this CSS property.

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;

// Non standard for webkit
word-break: break-word;
```

in table cell `td` you can add this CSS.

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;

     // Non standard for webkit
     word-break: break-word;
}
```

Here is the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/6zJR4/1/

After understanding the actual requirement it would be good to use a very tiny jquery plugin called `Succinct` can help you. here is the link. http://micjamking.github.io/succinct/

Comment: I do not want to break the text, i want to clip it.
Sorry the problem is hard to explain :)

Comment: I added an example fiddle, which should explain my goal.

Comment: just saw what you exactly looking. you have to define some `min-width` in 'td`.

Comment: A jquery plugin 'Succinct' for truncating multiple lines of text will help you. Here is the link you can find http://micjamking.github.io/succinct/

Answer (score 0):

add `width` to your `table`and it would wrap contents inside table equal to  div width, but it wont show excess text

[**Demo of what u need exactly**](http://jsfiddle.net/6zJR4/4/)

```
table.tbl{
    width:100%; /* this will make table equal to div width and clip excess contents*/
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

and, to show excess text,`word-break` them

```
table.tbl{
    width:100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6zJR4/3/)

Comment: i saw ur requirement, remove `break-word` and that pretty much solves your probs i guess....`width` is what u need in `table`s

Comment: But now the second and third column get clipped even if the first column still has free space:
http://jsfiddle.net/6zJR4/5/.

Compare it to the "What i want table"

Comment: u want clipping or `td`s to occupy the adjacent free space of other `td`s??

Comment: Both. I want the td's to take all free space and then when no space is available anymore i want to biggest columns get clipped as much as needed.

Comment: is the number of `td`s fixed?? or is it dynamic in table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49168/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-nick-russler)